# scikit-learn pipeline preprocessing with TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' when fitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

Hi I am currently working on a classification problem using scikit-learn pipeline, I have used pipeline preprocessing to impute missing value for numeric and categorical columns respectively, however, still have TypeError. I know there are many similar questions regarding this but I've tried their fixes and still didn't solve the problem. My dataset contains both object, float64, and int64, some of records are nulls (showing NaN).

This is the error message I got:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

So I impute them with median and 'missing' respectively. Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, Pipeline
from mlxtend.preprocessing import DenseTransformer

numeric_features=X.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns
numeric_transformer=Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer',SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler',StandardScaler())])

categorical_features=X.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
categorical_transformer=Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer',SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot',OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
    ('to_dense', DenseTransformer())])

preprocessor=ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num',numeric_transformer,numeric_features),
    ('cat',categorical_transformer,categorical_features)])

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])
rf.fit(X_train1, Y_train1) #--> this is when the error message points to
```

My question is that I thought the preprocessor part will impute and handle the missing cells, why would there still be the type error. Did I do something wrong?

Really appreciate the help. Any suggestions to fix this are welcome!! Thanks!!

Comment: I can't see any problems with the pipeline you defined. I also tested it on a dummy dataset and did not run in any issues. Can you include a small sample of your dataset that reproduces the error?

Comment: sorry about my late response. The data I was working on contains confidential information so i wasn't able to share. However, I tried to run with a subset of variables, this error only occurs when 1 of the variables is included in the data. So I look into the 1 variables, and found its data type being "object", but some of them are integer (value such as 30, 28), float (value such as: 30.0, 28.0, 2.5 etc), and string (L, D, G etc). I made the integer and float data type consistent and now somehow it works...I'll try again with large sample to see if this error occurs again. Thanks!!